# So if string is not NilLiteralConvertible... what do some string functions return?

Tags: ios, swift, option-type

Let's assume the following code:

```
let url = "http://%20abc"
let urlString = url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
if urlString != nil {
    println("done")
}
```

`stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` should return an optional String. So let's unwrap it. Now what happens when it actually 'fails' and doesn't return a string?

String is not a NilLiteralConvertible, therefore there is a compiler error on the next line. I am really confused here - so what should I compare the `urlString` with if I assume that `url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` is an unwrapped optional? Obviously it is  not working with nil.

Please note I could leave the urlString as an optional value and then unwrap it, etc. That's not the point. The point is this exact case. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Posted this question 30 seconds ago and got a downvote. Care to explain, dear downvoter, why?

Comment: I didn't down vote but I guess because your code is an obvious non-sequitur. As per the answer you implicitly unwrap the optional and then try and treat it as an optional

Comment: And probably also because it's unclear exactly what this has to do with `NilLiteralConvertible`, which isn't the error this code generates.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks Paul, ...makes no sense to me anyway but whatever. I thought SO was here to help out, even with "you implicitly unwrap the optional and then try and treat it as an optional". Even that's appreciated. The explanation of my assumption is in the comment of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> let url = "http://%20abc"
> let urlString = url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding!
> if urlString != nil {
>     println("done")
> }
> ```

The error I get there is on the `!=`, where it says:

> Binary operator `!=` cannot be applied to operands of the type `String` and `nil`

Which makes sense.  Why would we even *want* to use any comparison operator between `String` and `nil`.  A `String` **cannot** be `nil`.

Now, `url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` has a return type of `String?`, but we're using the implicitly unwrapped optional, which means that `urlString` will either be a `String` and have a value, or we'll get a fatal error (unexpectedly found `nil` unwrapping an optional).

If we *remove* our implicit unwrap operator:

```
let url = "http://%20abc"
let urlString = url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding
if urlString != nil {
    println("done")
}
```

Now the code is perfectly happy.  Instead of being a `String`, our variable, `urlString` is now a `String?`.  And we can use `!=` to compare any optional with `nil` because optionals *can be nil*!

But perhaps the most *Swifty* way of writing this looks like this:

```
let url = "http://%20abc"
if let urlString = url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding {
    // do something with urlString
    println("done")
}
```

In this scenario, `urlString` is of type `String`, so we don't have to unwrap it, but the `if` block only enters (and we can only use the `urlString` within the `if` block) if and only if `url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding` returns a non-nil.

---

And for the record, if we're not actually going to do anything with `urlString`, we have the following two options:

```
if url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding != nil {
    println("done")
}
```

and also:

```
if let _ = url.stringByRemovingPercentEncoding {
    println("done")
}
```

Comment: Oh, I see now. I know why it happens, I just didn't quite grasp why it cannot be nil if it is implicitly unwrapped. I could have just put *let urlString: String!* I assumed that the compiler actually figures that out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Tread with extraordinary caution with the `!`.  I highly recommend you not use it unless you actually *really* know what you're doing.  You're just going to be continuously bumping into "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping optional" problems.