# Multiplying variables and doubles in swift

Tags: swift, variables, double, multiplication

I'm a designer looking into learning Swift and I'm a beginner.

I have no experience whatsoever.

I'm trying to create a tip calculator using basic code in Xcode's playground.

Here is what I have so far.

```
var billBeforeTax = 100
var taxPercentage = 0.12
var tax = billBeforeTax * taxPercentage
```

I get the error:

> Binary operator '*' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'Double'

Does this mean I can't multiply doubles?

Am I missing any of the basic concepts of variables and doubles here?

Comment: On an unrelated note - it's preferred that, where you can, you use `let` instead of `var`.

Comment: This is a duplicate... let me just find what it's a duplicate of...

Comment: possible duplicate of [So if string is not NilLiteralConvertible... what do some string functions return?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29835099/so-if-string-is-not-nilliteralconvertible-what-do-some-string-functions-retur)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can only multiple two of the same data type.

```
var billBeforeTax = 100 // Interpreted as an Integer
var taxPercentage = 0.12 // Interpreted as a Double
var tax = billBeforeTax * taxPercentage // Integer * Double = error
```

If you declare `billBeforeTax` like so..

```
var billBeforeTax = 100.0
```

It will be interpreted as a Double and the multiplication will work. Or you could also do the following.

```
var billBeforeTax = 100
var taxPercentage = 0.12
var tax = Double(billBeforeTax) * taxPercentage // Convert billBeforeTax to a double before multiplying.
```

Comment: Swift is very sensitive about the types. For the most of time, you could not do operation between two variables of the different type. Good Answer.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to cast your int variable to Double as below:

```
    var billBeforeTax = 100
    var taxPercentage = 0.12
    var tax = Double(billBeforeTax) * taxPercentage
```